# What is the best free source for generating g-code

Tags: diy-3d-printer, g-code

Ok so i have built a 3d printer from old cd rom drives. Before installing the 3d pen(extruder/hotend) i used www.makercam.com to export i file containing a star. With a marker attached the machone successfully drew a star. Now i have the 3d pen but using makercam i am not having any luck. Is there a better way to generate files for my new toy?

Comment: I would like to be able to generate my own files so it will have some functionality but something to test it with would be great

Comment: Are you looking for a way to generated the g-code or to create a model?

Comment: Using tinkercam you can export to.obj or .stl however the controllers i have installed take .nc files. Is there a way to convert or do i need a different controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The g code is generated by a program like slic3r, skeinforge or cura. These programs import a CAD model slilce it into layers and output the gcode required to print each layer.